# Name for intermediate aggregated data

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, aggregate

We have raw data and aggregated data as well as sometimes multiple levels of aggregation between.  Is there a name for the data in that intermediate "state" of aggregation?

Just like how we have Real time, near real time and historical...

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I've seen these intermediate levels referred to by the "grain" of the aggregation at which the data is stored.

For example, if you have an intermediate aggregation in which the data is stored at the level of a person for a day, we would call that the person-day grain. This can be applied generically throughout most schemas.